# AndroidManifest.xml.orig: Operation not permitted in Apktool

Tags: android, linux, apktool

I want to edit an APK file, for this purpose I use the following command in Linux (Kali):

```
apktool d ed28.apk
```

and result is:

```
 I: Using Apktool 2.6.1-dirty on ed28.apk I: Loading resource table...
 I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources... I: Loading resource
 table from file: /home/mahdi/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk I:
 Regular manifest package... I: Decoding file-resources... I: Decoding
values */* XMLs... I: Baksmaling classes.dex... I: Copying assets and
 libs... I: Copying unknown files... I: Copying original files...
```

After editing one of the smalli files, i want to recompile it again, so i used this command:

```
apktool b -d -f ed28
```

but i get this error:

> I: Using Apktool 2.6.1-dirty I: Smaling smali folder into
> classes.dex...
> ed28/AndroidManifest.xml.orig: Operation not permitted

I tried this too and the result was the same

`apktool b -d -f ed28 --use-aapt2`

Comment: have you tried sudo or run this command under admin privileges?

Comment: Also, if you only need to make changes in smalli have a look at "-r, --no-res" cmd options